# Count each element within XML node instead of continuous counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

How to improve this code in the part where the number of `SpelementUnit` elements are counted (SpelementElement_Count column)?

Instead of a continuous counting within the entire XML I need a SpelementUnit's sequences count separately.
(Inside each `EntitySpatial`--> `SpatialElement` elements)

While this code counts from 1 to 7. When i need like 1,2 - 1,2,3 - 1,2

CODE

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Parcels>
    <Parcel ID="1">
        <EntitySpatial>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="100.2" Y="-100.2"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="100.3" Y="-100.3"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="100.4" Y="-100.4"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="100.5" Y="-100.5"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
        </EntitySpatial>
    </Parcel>
    <Parcel ID="2">
        <EntitySpatial>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="200.1" Y="-200.1"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit>
                    <Ordinate X="200.2" Y="-200.2"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
        </EntitySpatial>
    </Parcel>
</Parcels>';


SELECT base.value('@ID', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Parcel_ID
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY outr) as SpatialElement_Count
--     ,outr2.value('@PointNum', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS PointNum
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@X)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_X
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@Y)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_Y
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY outr2) as SpelementElement_Count 
FROM @xml.nodes('Parcels/Parcel') as x(base)
    OUTER APPLY base.nodes('EntitySpatial/SpatialElement') AS B(outr)
    OUTER APPLY outr.nodes('SpelementUnit') AS C(outr2);
```

**Desired output** (main column is "SpelementElement_Count")

```
 +-----------+---------------------+-----  -----+------------+------------------------+
| Parcel_ID | SpatialElement_Count | Ordinate_X | Ordinate_Y | SpelementElement_Count |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+------------------------+
|         1 |                    1 |      100.1 |     -100.1 |                      1 |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.2 |     -100.2 |                      2 |
|         1 |                    2 |      100.3 |     -100.3 |                      1 |
|         1 |                    2 |      100.4 |     -100.4 |                      2 |
|         1 |                    2 |      100.5 |     -100.5 |                      3 |
|         2 |                    3 |      200.1 |     -200.1 |                      1 |
|         2 |                    3 |      200.2 |     -200.2 |                      2 |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: You're missing a `PARTITION BY` in your `DENSE_RANK`, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PARTITION BY` when [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause is used. It simply

> Divides the query result set into partitions. The window function is
> applied to each partition separately and computation restarts for each
> partition.

You can think for `PARTITION BY` in `OVER` clause, as `GROUP BY` clause when aggregate function is used.

```
SELECT base.value('@ID', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Parcel_ID
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY outr) as SpatialElement_Count
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@X)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_X
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@Y)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_Y
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY outr ORDER BY outr2) as SpelementElement_Count 
FROM @xml.nodes('Parcels/Parcel') as x(base)
    OUTER APPLY base.nodes('EntitySpatial/SpatialElement') AS B(outr)
    OUTER APPLY outr.nodes('SpelementUnit') AS C(outr2);
```